# Get more than 10 results by google search API in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get 10 pages result listed using the following cod below. When i run the URL directly i get a json string but using this in code it does not returns anything. Please tell me where i am doing wrong.

```
$url =  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=CompTIA A+ Complete Study Guide Authorized Courseware site:.edu&start=20";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($body,true);
    print_r($json);
```

Now i am using the following code but it outputs only four entries of a page. Please tell me where i am doing wrong.

```
$term = "CompTIA A+ Training Kit Microsoft Press Training Kit";
for($i=0;$i<=90;$i+=10)
        {
            $term = $val.' site:.edu';
            $query = urlencode($term);
            $url   = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=' . $query . '&start='.$i;

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $body = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            $json = json_decode($body,true);

            //print_r($json);
            foreach($json['responseData']['results'] as $data)
            {
                echo '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td>'.$url.'</td><td>'.$k.'</td><td>'.$val.'</td><td>'.$data['visibleUrl'].'</td><td>'.$data['unescapedUrl'].'</td><td>'.$data['content'].'</td></tr>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: `gives me an error` -> what does the error say?

Comment: I am getting 400 error when i run the following code: $site_url =  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=CompTIA A+ Complete Study Guide Authorized Courseware site:.edu&start=20";

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0; // set to zero for no timeout
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// display file
echo $file_contents;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode)

```
$query = urlencode('CompTIA A+ Complete Study Guide Authorized Courseware site:.edu');
$url   = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=' . $query . '&start=20';
```